# Cannot boot Android-x86 on PC - Emergency remount

Tags: boot, reboot, mount, system-error, android-x86

I have a 10.1 inch notebook with Linux, but would like to dualboot with Android x86. The ISO file works perfectly in VirtualBox, VMware, and on Live USB. I have tried both install from the Install program and copying the .img files onto a partition, then adding the boot entry to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. I get the following displayed on my screen when I select the boot entry.

```
Detecting Android-x86... found at /dev/sda2
[     3.697517] sysrq: SysRq: Emergency remount R/0
```

Then it reboots to the GRUB menu.

How do I fix this, and boot Android-x86?

I have an HP-e010nr with an AMD A4 dual core@1.0Ghz, 2GB ram, and I am trying to start Android-x86_64 7.1 on a 32GB partition (no fake sdcard).

I have stored everything in the parition in an "Android" directory.

My boot code is:

```
set root = (hd0,2) #/dev/sda2 in the partition where Android-x86 is located
kernel /Android/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive buildvariant=userdebug SRC=/Android/
initrd /Android/initrd.img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I ended up installing LineageOS x86 14.1 instead of Android x86, however, these instructions should still work for Android x86)

After trying to find my answer, I ended up removing my partition for Android-x86 and installing the LineageOS 14.1 .rpm. On Debian Linux (or Debian-based, like Ubuntu) install it with:

```
sudo alien -ci cm-x86_14.1.rpm
```

where cm-x86_14.1.rpm is your Android x86 package. If you are told alien is not installed, type `sudo apt install alien` before repeating.

After a while, it will convert into a .deb and then install. However, you will get the following messages:

```
/boot/grub/custom.cfg: No such file or directory
/boot/grub/custom.cfg: No such file or directory
```

In order to add the boot code that failed to be added, put the following in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Android-x86 14.1-r2" {
    search --set=root --file /cm-x86-14.1-r2/kernel
    linux /cm-x86-14.1-r2/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive buildvariant=userdebug 
    initrd /cm-x86-14.1-r2/initrd.img
}
menuentry "Android-x86 14.1-r2 (DEBUG mode)" {
    search --set=root --file /cm-x86-14.1-r2/kernel
    linux /cm-x86-14.1-r2/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive buildvariant=userdebug DEBUG=2
    initrd /cm-x86-14.1-r2/initrd.img
}
```

(I got the boot code from the cm-x86 postinit script)

Replace `cm-x86-14.1-r2` with the location of Android-x86 (for example: `android-x86-7.1-r1`), and replace the 14.1 in `Android-x86 14.1-r2` with your Android version number (like 7.1 or 8.1).

Then, reboot and select `Android-x86 14.1-r2` to boot Android.